# Javascript line break in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i give a line break in the string text?
I want to give a line break in this line:
"Monday September 21 at 11:00am - September 24 at 12:00pm Pacific Time"

in the below code.

This is what I am doing.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div.when ul.details p:contains("Sunday, September 20, 2015 - Thursday, September 24, 2015")').text('Monday September 21 at 11:00am - September 24 at 12:00pm Pacific Time ');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function and put `<br>` wherever you want line break.

```
$('div.when ul.details p:contains("Sunday, September 20, 2015 - Thursday, September 24, 2015")')
    .html('Monday<br>September 21 at 11:00am - September 24 at 12:00pm Pacific Time ');
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('div')
    .html('Monday<br>September 21 at 11:00am - September 24 at 12:00pm Pacific Time ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
</div>
```